# How to multiply cells in a row, gridview

Tags: c#

When i click a button i want to multiply cells in a row and then output the result into another cell but do it individually for each row, the code i have right now

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow Column in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
                    {
                        if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value == null)
                        {
                            Column.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["FinalPrice"].Index].Value = (Convert.ToDouble(Column.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["Price"].Index].Value) * Convert.ToDouble(Column.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["Amount"].Index].Value));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Column.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["FinalPrice"].Index].Value = (Convert.ToDouble(Column.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["Price"].Index].Value) * Convert.ToDouble(Column.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["Discount"].Index].Value)) * Convert.ToDouble(Column.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["Amount"].Index].Value);
                        }

                    }

                }
```

The problem is that if one cell shows null on any row than it runs this code for all the rows

```
Column.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["FinalPrice"].Index].Value = (Convert.ToDouble(Column.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["Price"].Index].Value) * Convert.ToDouble(Column.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["Amount"].Index].Value));
```

[For each row i want to check if the discount cell is null and if so multiply the amount and price cell or if it isn't multiply the amount price and discount cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGKY0.png)

Comment: What is the question ?  i didn't understand what you want to do and what is your problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a straight answer, but alternative approach which should eliminate this and similar problems.
Alternative approach would be to extract UI logic from the actual calculation

Create a class to represent the data in the row

```
public class Purchase
{
    public string Item { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal? Discount { get; set; }

    public decimal FinalPrice = Price * Amount * Discount.GetValueOrDefault(1.0m);
}
```

To display purchases inn the DataGridView you need only one line of code

```
var purchases = LoadPurchasesFromDatabase();

dataGridView.DataSource = purchases;
```

Values changes in the instance of `Purchase` class will automatically update DataGridView.

If you need to support adding and removing purchases from the collection, then you need make collection of purchases to be of type `BindingList<Purchase>`

By extracting purchase logic our of UI code you get rid of tedious and redundant conversion, column and datagridview row looping.